# Python: map errno to subclass of OSError

Tags: python, subclass, errno, oserror

I have a Python 3 program which calls a C function. The C function returns an integer: 0 upon success, or the appropriate `errno` upon failure. Upon failure, the Python code could simply raise `OSError`. But I'd rather it raise the appropriate subclass of `OSError`.

For example, if the Python program gets the return code of 2, it should raise `FileNotFoundError`, a subclass of `OSError`. I can already find the correct subclass by doing the following three steps. Obviously, performance is not an issue because I need to do these steps only once per version of Python 3 for all values of `errno`, and cache the results.

1. Find all the subclasses of `OSError`. This is easy using `__subclass__`, recursively if necessary.
2. Map all the `errno` values to names. For example, if `errno` is 2, that should map to `ENOENT`. This is done by parsing the appropriate C include file. On FreeBSD, for example, that file would be `/usr/include/errno.h`.
3. Map `errno` names to `OSError` subclasses. This can be done by parsing the HTML code in, for example, http://docs.python.org/release/3.8.2/library/exceptions.html

But step 3 is really, really hokey. Is there a way I can do that step without parsing the documentation? Is there something I can inspect somehow in the Python that's sitting on my local host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the documentation I believe that this translation is done automatically. if you for example call:

```
raise OSError(2, 'this went wrong') # here the 2 corresponds to the error given by C
# raises -> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] this went wrong
```

For the exact mapping used here go to the [page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#os-exceptions) you reference and look at the OS exceptions section.

Comment: Your belief is correct, and I can't believe I didn't even try that first! Interestingly, it only uses the subclass if you include that second argument, the string; the string may be empty.